# Remove json object key value using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have json response and I want to remove few object key values from it and store the edited response on other part so that I can use again.

I know by using simple javascript, but I don't have any idea in angularjs.

#### Json response

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "XYZ": [],
    "ABC": [
        {
            "$id": "41",
            "ID": 1,
            "Order": 0,
            "Delay": 0,
            "Name": "abc",
            "Count": "9",
            "Storage": 3,
            "Groups": []
        }
    ],
    "Projected": 2019
}
```

Now from this Json file I want to filter out

`"$id": "41"`,`"ID": 1`,`"Order": 0`,
 `"Delay": 0`, `"Groups": []`, `"Name": "abc"`

So my new json structure will be like this which I want to store:

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "XYZ": [],
    "ABC": [
        {
            "Count": "9",
            "Storage": 3
        }
    ],
    "Projected": 2019
}
```

Any method to achieve ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `angularJS` ,  you can use Javascript. Use `Object.delete` or some other way around

Comment: Angular don't have a particular method for this. Except angular.forEach. You must use vanilla js.

Comment: @ShashankVivek I got you , but it has something to do as I want to filter it out as soon as data is loaded from service before loading in controller. tried with `object.delete` didn't worked out.

Comment: The answer of @Lorenz will help you. Let us know if you need more explanation

Answer (score 4):

You don't need some magic angular stuff. You can just use plain old JavaScript.
My apporach iterates through all the items in the `ABC` array and `delete`s all properties defined in the `props` array. Note, that this actively modifies the `ABC` array items.

```js
const obj = {
    "$id": "1",
    "XYZ": [],
    "ABC": [
        {
            "$id": "41",
            "ID": 1,
            "Order": 0,
            "Delay": 0,
            "Name": "abc",
            "Count": "9",
            "Storage": 3,
            "Groups": []
        }
    ],
    "Projected": 2019
}

// Now from this Json file I want to filter out

const props = ["$id", "ID", "Order", "Delay", "Groups", "Name"];
props.forEach(prop => {
    obj.ABC.forEach(abc => {
      delete abc[prop];
    });
});

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: I tried this part in my code `props.forEach(prop => {
        $scope.list.ABC.forEach(ABC=> {
         delete ABC[props];
       });` its is showing error :- `typeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at props.forEach.prop`

Comment: You should take care which variables you want to delete. You want to delete all variables declared in `props`, iteratered by `forEach`, assigning the name `prop`. So you want something like `props.forEach(prop => { $scope.list.ABC.forEach(abc=> { delete abc[prop]; });`. Take care: `delete abc[prop]`, **not** `delete abc[props]`. If that does not work, would you mind givin us a complete code example?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the other solutions. 
If we have a variable called json.
This method is simple

```
let len = json.ABC.length;
for (let i=0;i<len;i++){
    delete json.ABC[i].$id;
    delete json.ABC[i].ID;
    delete json.ABC[i].Order;
    delete json.ABC[i].Delay;
    delete json.ABC[i].Groups;
    delete json.ABC[i].Name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
let json = {
    "$id": "1",
    "XYZ": [],
    "ABC": [
        {
            "$id": "41",
            "ID": 1,
            "Order": 0,
            "Delay": 0,
            "Name": "abc",
            "Count": "9",
            "Storage": 3,
            "Groups": []
        }
    ],
    "Projected": 2019
};

json["ABC"] = json["ABC"].map(obj => ({
  "Count": obj["Count"],
  "Storage": obj["Storage"]
}));
// or dynamic way
let keepkeys = ["Storage", "Count"];
json["ABC"] = json["ABC"].map(obj => {
  let newObj = {};
   keepkeys.forEach(key => newObj[key] = obj[key]);
  return newObj;
});
console.log(json)
```

Comment: Let me try this.